# Angularjs Apply toggle function to only the clicked button inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, this, togglebutton

I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/2rkd9xjq/) exclusively to adress my problem. I am `ng-repeat`ing certain section. I have a toggle functionality to be implemented inside it. However, when I click the button, function gets triggered for all the repeated items. This works fine when not using `ng-repeat` inspite of using the same function name on click. Below is the code. I guess there is something like the `this` operator that I can make use here. My code so far (I created this for the fiddle and not the original),

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="CommentController">
        <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
            <button ng-click="showDiv()" class="review">{{lists[$index]}}</button>
            <div ng-show="hiddenDiv">This is the div to be toggled on clicking any of the above button. And they do so as they make use of <i>same function on click.</i>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CommentController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hiddenDiv = true;
    $scope.showDiv = function () {
        $scope.hiddenDiv = !$scope.hiddenDiv;
    };
    $scope.lists = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
});
```

Comment: Here is the toggle that works without `ng-repeat` http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/jhhtkuuv/3/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you need to collapse one specific repeat according to clicked button try followings,

modify the button as

```
<button ng-click="hiddenDiv = !hiddenDiv" class="review">{{lists[$index]}}</button>
```

and remove the `$scope.showDiv` function from controller

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ahh30tyo/)

---

**DESCRIPTION**

if you use like,

```
 <button ng-click="showDiv()" class="review">{{lists[$index]}}</button>
```

when clicking the button will trigger the `$scope.showDiv` function from controller, and in that function `$scope.hiddenDiv` property will toggle, and **note that $scope.hiddenDiv** will visible to whole controller that means its common for all the controller scope, so if you change it once all other things which using that property will change,

but if use

```
<button ng-click="hiddenDiv = !hiddenDiv" class="review">{{lists[$index]}}</button>
```

then there will be a `hiddenDiv` property for each and every repeat since `ng-repeat` is creating a child scope ([DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)). so there is a separate `hiddenDiv` property for a one specific repeat and its not visible to others its visible just for the relevant repeat.

---

if you use

```
<button ng-click="myData.hiddenDiv = !myData.hiddenDiv" class="review">{{lists[$index]}}</button>
```

note that your using **`myData.hiddenDiv` instead of `hiddenDiv`**,
in this case angular will check `hiddenDiv` property of `myData` object with in `ng-repeat` child scope and then angular realize there is no something called `myData` in the child scope and then it will search it in the parent scope and realized property exists at there and that property is common for all the repeats like using the `showDiv()` function. but if u use `hiddenDiv` without then angular will search it in the `ng-repeat` child scope and create a new child scope variable after realizing the absence of the  `hiddenDiv` with in child scope.

see the Prototypal Inheritance. there is a good description [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs).

and please check [**this**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#ngRepeat) description too

Comment: glad to help you and i added some description and hope it will help you to understand the issue better. :)

Comment: I totally appreciate your help. Since I am a beginner, I would also appreciate if you address in your description what happened here when I slightly modified things. http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/pq72u7ge/1/

Comment: This is very helpful information. Thanks for your time toress. Have a nice day.

Comment: its glad to help you. :) happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Badly needed this :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a array instead of a single variable and pass the index in the function call so that it will not toggle every thing in one action.

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="CommentController">
    <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
        <button ng-click="showDiv($index)" class="review">{{lists[$index]}}</button>
        <div ng-show="!hiddenDiv[$index]">This is the div to be toggled on clicking any of the above button. And they do so as they make use of <i>same function on click.</i>
        <input type="text" ng-model="textModel[$index]"/>{{textModel[$index]}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CommentController', function ($scope) {
$scope.hiddenDiv=[];
$scope.textModel=[];
$scope.showDiv = function (index) {
    $scope.hiddenDiv[index] = !$scope.hiddenDiv[index];
    $scope.textModel[index]=null;
};
$scope.lists = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paje007/85vp9zme/6/

In this way, if you want to perform any action in the function you can do that also, like in the fiddle. Here I am clearing the text input on hide.

Comment: You somehow read my mind that it is for a comment box :) This one works well too. Thank you.